# maven nsis: Avoid duplicate file uploading to nexus

Tags: maven

I am using maven nsis-maven-plugin.1.0 plugin which creates myapp-1.0.1_Setup_INTERNAL.exe under the target folder.
And this internally invokes the maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install and attaches the myapp-1.0.1.exe.
Here is my confusion, even though I mentioned the `<outputFile>` tag with my preferred .exe file, the NSIS is not considering it.

So, finally there are 2 .exes which get uploaded to Nexus. One is myapp-1.0.1_Setup_INTERNAL.exe and the other is myapp-1.0.1.exe.
I want to avoid uploading the file myapp-1.0.1.exe.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>nsis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <makensisBin>${project.build.directory}/NSIS/makensis.exe</makensisBin>
    <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}_Setup_INTERNAL.exe</outputFile>
    <setupScript>${project.build.directory}/gen/internal-installer.nsi</setupScript>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```